# ignore-package-exit-codes does not work in Chocolatey v0.9.10.2 with Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chocolatey

I am trying to install Windows Azure Powershell with the chocolatey_package in Chef. The new 0.9.10.2 version of Chocolatey returns the application exit code that can be other than 0 even after a successful install.

```
      0 - most widely used success exit code
      1605 - (MSI uninstall) - the product is not found, could have already been uninstalled
      1614 (MSI uninstall) - the product is uninstalled
      1641 (MSI) - restart initiated
      3010 (MSI, InnoSetup can be passed to provide this) - restart required
```

In this case the code is 3010, because the installation succeeded, but a reboot is needed. Chef displays the following message: 
`Expected process to exit with [0], but received '3010'`.
For Chef 0 is the only success exit code. I have tried to send options to Chocolatey to ignore the application exit code and send 0 to Chef, but none of the formats seem to work:

```
    chocolatey_package 'windowsazurepowershell' do
      options "--ignore-package-exit-codes=true"
    end
```

I have also tried

```
      options "--ignore-package-exit-codes=3010"
      options "--use-package-exit-codes=false"
```

Based on the documentation the following options should be valid:

`ignorepackagecodes ignorepackageexitcodes ignore-package-codes ignore-package-exit-codes`
`usepackagecodes usepackageexitcodes use-package-codes use-package-exit-codes`

EDIT

Thanks for the help, I have tested the new 0.9.10.3 version of Chocolatey, and works great with

```
chocolatey_package 'windowsazurepowershell' do
  options "--ignore-package-exit-codes"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug in 0.9.10, which is fixed in 0.9.10.3. See https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/827 for details.

Comment: I have tested the fix and works great with
   `chocolatey_package 'windowsazurepowershell' do`
      `options "--ignore-package-exit-codes"`
    `end`

Answer (score 0):

This is being tracked in https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/5030. There is not a great solution right now other than what that ticket shows.